# Is there a way to unify the definitions of permutations as bijections and permutations as arrangements?

Tags: permutations, definition

I'm kind of new to the idea of permutations being defined as bijections on a set. Please be patient and bear with me. Let's start with the definitions.

**Definition 1:** A permutation is a bijection from a set onto itself.

**Definition 2:** A permutation (arrangement) of a set $X$ is a bijection from $\{1,2, \ldots, |X|\} \to X$.

---

Just to explain the definition 2 a bit further:  $bac= (b,a,c)$ is permutation of $\{a, b , c\}$ because you can define $f:\{1,2,3 \} \to \{a,b,c\}$ given by $f(1)=b, f(2)=a, f(3)=c$.

---

(For clarity, my question is in bold text below in case you get confused and start wondering where this is going.)

My thoughts: Definition 2 allows you conveniently use a tuple because a permutation is defined as a finite sequence. The drawback of definition 2 is that you can only permute the elements of a *finite* set. (I think... unless? Correct me if I'm wrong.)

As for definition 1, you cannot use the tuple notation or simply write the permutation as: $bac$ because there is no notion of ordering generally, on a set $X$. In that, there is no "first" element or second or so on.

Should I just take it with a pinch of salt that the two definitions are just different? Or **is there a smart way to sort of "unify" the two definitions?** I suppose if you take the set $X=\{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ then you could "unify" the two definitions, for instance $(2,1,3)= \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 &3 \\ 2 & 1 & 3 \end{matrix}\right)$ but this doesn't quite answer the question for a general set $X$ with no ordering. But here $X$ may be infinite as well.

Any nice intuition would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In some senses, self-bijections and linear orderings are fundamentally different structures, even though the number of them on a given finite set $X$ is the same (unless $X$ has some given additional structure like a special linear ordering). For example, on a pure finite set $X$, all $n!$ linear orderings look alike (under relabeling) whereas bijections partition into conjugacy classes. The double use or the term permutation just confuses the issue, IMO. 

Comment: If $X$ is finite and you select one "special" bijection from $\{1,2, \ldots, |X|\} \to X$, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between the permutations of definition $1$ and the permutations of definition $2$: a definition-$1$ permutation is the composition of the inverse of the special bijection followed by a definition-$2$ permutation.

Comment: @DavidK So what you're basically saying is that I should just go ahead and order the elements of $X$? Fair enough! 

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the idea. Is it a good idea? I don't know!

Comment: @DavidK Well it's something. Frankly, I don't see a way the two definitions could be equivalent. One requires the ordering of objects and renames them, other just "renames" the objects but doesn't hurt to be hopeful.

Comment: I don't think either definition requires the set $X$ itself to have any ordering. Each permutation of $X$ in definition 2 produces a different ordering of $X,$ but that's after the permutation. The "special" permutation is essentially a total ordering on $X$ that would allow you to identify the permutations of definition 1 with tuples. But I would suppose that in some circumstances one would like to be completely free of any particular total ordering of $X$, so a "special" permutation would be obnoxious.

Comment: Any particular bijection between linear orderings and the symmetric group will force you to have a special linear ordering, namely the one corresponding to the identity permutation. So if you are working with pure unordered set $X$, the sets of lin. orderings and self-bijections on $X$, though identical in size, are not naturally (combinatorially) isomorphic to each other.